# Video player that can be controlled by Socket / TCP

Tags: windows-7, video, remote-control, tcp, sockets

Is there a Video Player that can be controlled with TCP?

I think VLC supports this - but I can't find any easy to follow instructions on how to do this.

I will be using this on a windows 7 machine, and would like to be able to send the following commands over a socket connection:

- Play Video 1
- Play Video 2
- Stop

Answer (score 0):

VLC seemed difficult to get working correctly.

My colleague opted for using Key Note and some apple scripts in the end - worked brilliantly, and it made it easy to add slides etc for holding images in between movies.